# VBA: Search and select last found string in a column containing duplicate entries

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am trying to search a column that has duplicate entries of information. I want to select the last found occurence of the string in the column. How can I do this?

If possible, please show me how this can be done with the Selection.Find method.

```
Columns("A:A").Select

Selection.Find(What:="foobar", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I was looking for. By setting the SearchDirection property to xlPrevious, it will find the last value in the range. Then the cell can be focused on by using the .Select method. However, if the value that is being searched is a substring of other values within the column, it may select the wrong cell. This is solved by using a while loop that checks the value of the cell it finds, and keeps searching the previous value if it is not the string we are looking for.

```
Sub FindLast()
Dim fc As Range
Dim my_var As String
Dim cell_check As Variant
my_var = "String 1"

Set fc = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Find(what:=my_var, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
fc.Select
cell_check = ActiveCell.Value

While cell_check <> my_var
    Set fc = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").FindPrevious(after:=fc)
    fc.Select
    cell_check = ActiveCell.Value
Wend

End Sub
```

I found the solution by reading the documentation on Microsofts website.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findprevious

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FindAndSelectAll()
    Dim str As String, cll As Range, c As Range
    Dim rSearch As Range

    Set rSearch = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    With rSearch
        For Each cll In rSearch
            Set c = .Find(cll.Value2, _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

            If Not c Is Nothing And cll.Row < c.Row Then
                Range(c.Address).Interior.Color = 65535
            End If

        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]